# variable in this class does not name a type C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use log4cpp in my program (*nix machine - Ubuntu 12.10, Codeblocks) to create logs at various instances in the program.

**LoggerMain.h**

```
#include "log4cpp/Category.hh"
#include "log4cpp/Appender.hh"
#include "log4cpp/FileAppender.hh"
#include "log4cpp/OstreamAppender.hh"
#include "log4cpp/Layout.hh"
#include "log4cpp/BasicLayout.hh"
#include "log4cpp/Priority.hh"
```

**MainProgram.h**

```
#include "LoggerMain.h"

MainProgram{
public:
log4cpp::Appender *appender;
};
```

**MainProgram.cpp**

```
appender = new log4cpp::FileAppender("default","program.log"); //getting error here
appender->setLayout(new log4cpp::BasicLayout());
log4cpp::Category& root = log4cpp::Category::getRoot();

main{
//will use root here for loggin
}
```

Error:
**src/MainProgram.cpp|21|error: ‘appender’ in ‘class MainProgram’ does not name a type|**

What's going wrong? I am basically doing the same thing as in the log4cpp simple example documentation [here](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/#simpleexample)

Comment: Is that *all* of MainProgram.cpp? Because I'm not seeing any #include statements, or even a function definition.

Comment: @JasonD: No. It isn't. The program itself was very long so I trimmed ti to show only the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have operations outside function, put below code into MainProgram construction,

```
MainProgram::MainProgram(){
  appender = new log4cpp::FileAppender("default","program.log"); //getting error here
  appender->setLayout(new log4cpp::BasicLayout());
  log4cpp::Category& root = log4cpp::Category::getRoot();
}
```

You could use singleton mode for MainProgram

```
MainProgram{
public:
   MainProgram* instance(){
     if (!instance){
        instance = new MainProgram();
        return instance;
     } 
   }
   MainProgram()
   {
      appender = new new log4cpp::FileAppender("default","program.log"); //getting error here
      appender->setLayout(new log4cpp::BasicLayout());
   }
private:
   log4cpp::Appender *appender;
   MainProgram* instance;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   MainProgram::Instance();
}
```

Note, C++ supports two forms of main functions, you need to change main function to one of below forms:

```
int main() { /* ... */ }
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Also,I declared the `log4cpp::Category& root` in the MainProgram.h and tried to use it as `root = log4cpp::Category::getRoot();` but I then get an error saying  `‘log4cpp::Category& log4cpp::Category::operator=(const log4cpp::Category&)’ is private` Shouldn't I be using `root` globally across my program to write the logs or should I get instance each time in a function?

Comment: And btw when I include these things inside the function,I start getting errors saying : `undefined reference to `log4cpp::FileAppender::FileAppender(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, unsigned int)'|`

Comment: Got it. Linker flag was missing

Comment: Just an extra query that how do I use root across my program globally, without the need of initializing it each time in a function.

Comment: declare it as a static, but you need to figure out how `getRoot()` works from log4j document. it may initialize itself each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have code statements outside of functions. This should perhaps be inside the class constructor?

The compiler is expecting a declaration, which would start with a type. It says that `appender` isn't a type.

Comment: Also,I declared the `log4cpp::Category& root` in the MainProgram.h and tried to use it as `root = log4cpp::Category::getRoot();` but I then get an error saying  `‘log4cpp::Category& log4cpp::Category::operator=(const log4cpp::Category&)’ is private` Shouldn't I be using `root` globally across my program to write the logs or should I get instance each time in a function?

Comment: And btw when I include these things inside the function,I start getting errors saying : `undefined reference to `log4cpp::FileAppender::FileAppender(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, unsigned int)'|`

Comment: A difference is that in the example you link to, everything is *inside* the `main` function. You have put some of the code outside. That doesn't work (for any code).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not create an instance of `MainProgram`. Try something along these lines:

```
MainProgram mp;
mp.appender = new log4cpp::FileAppender("default","program.log");
```